# Is this the right way of implementing "Design by contract" pattern in PHP?

Tags: php, design-patterns, datacontract

I've discovered the "Design by contract" pattern and how to implement in in PHP. I can't find a real world example of how to do this in PHP. **First question** is am i'm doing it in the right way? **Second one is** why the assert callback is not honored?

A static class `Asserts` for reusable assertions:

```
class Asserts
{
    public static function absentOrNotNumeric($value)
    {
        return !isset($value) ? true : is_numeric($value);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
assert_options(ASSERT_ACTIVE,   true);
assert_options(ASSERT_BAIL,     true);
assert_options(ASSERT_WARNING,  true);
assert_options(ASSERT_CALLBACK, array('UseAsserts', 'onAssertFailure'));

class UseAsserts
{
    private $value;

    public function __construct($value)
    {
        // Single quotes are needed otherwise you'll get a
        // Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING 
        assert('Asserts::absentOrNotNumeric($value)');
        $this->value = $value;
    }

    public static function onAssertFailure($file, $line, $message)
    {
        throw new Exception($message);
    }
}

// This will trigger a warning and stops execution, but Exception is not thrown
$fail = new UseAsserts('Should fail.');
```

Only the (right) warning is triggered:

> Warning: assert() [function.assert]: Assertion
>   "Asserts::absetOrNotNumeric($value)" failed.

Comment: What warning does it trigger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your exception is being thrown, altering it to:

```
public static function onAssertFailure($file, $line, $message)
{
    echo "<hr>Assertion Failed:
    File '$file'<br />
    Line '$line'<br />
    Code '$code'<br /><hr />";
}
```

results in a display of the text, some testing discovers that if you alter this option

```
assert_options(ASSERT_BAIL,     false);
```

The exception will be thrown, so it seems that it bails on the execution prior to throwing the exception.

Hope that helps

Answer (score -1):

Your code: http://codepad.org/y10BlV8m

My code: http://codepad.org/slSX3HKd

Try using double quotes: `assert("Asserts::absentOrNotNumeric($value)");`

Comment: Again no, `assert` requires single quotes, see [assert](http://php.net/manual/en/function.assert.php) example on PHP website.